# Nginx with docker does not work with different port mapping

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, web, hugo

I have created a basic static website and I'm trying to deploy my site on nginx server with docker.

It works fine when I run `docker run -d -p 80:80 -v /path/to/site:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx`

But when I map it with different port like `-p 8080:80` it gives me a bad gateway error.

The initial homepage loads up fine `http://localhost:8080`,but when I try to navigate in the website like a blog post, it redirects to `http://localhost/blog` rather than `http://localhost:8080/blog`. I have not changed any configuration whatsoever, I have left it default.

Initially I thought it must be with my site but it works fine with httpd & docker. But I want to run it on a nginx server.

Please help me !!

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Docker or Nginx but is because your links don't have the port number in them. Nginx is just serving your files completely as-is.

Comment: Check out this repo: https://github.com/BertCatsburg/Nginx_in_Docker  In there a simple example on how to run nginx in docker with other websites. Let me know if you still have questions, then I add/answer them in the repo/

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to create a repo to explain in detail, the simple nginx site works fine. I really appreciate the concern shown.  I just want to add that I'm using ```hugo``` static site generator to build my website. How do I make my site work with dynamic ports cause it works fine if I just map it with port 80 ?

Comment: @HansKilian But it works fine with httpd and docker.

Comment: I can't see any way to make this work and I doubt it works with httpd without you telling httpd to rewrite links to port 8080. In your nginx setup, the only component that knows that you're running on port 8080 rather than port 80 is Docker.  Docker doesn't have the ability to rewrite your links from port 80 to port 8080 as they're served. You can get nginx to do it, but you have to tell it to.

Comment: I don't know how but it just works with httpd (apache2) ! How do I tell nginx to rewrite the links ?